# How to obtain the SonarQube taskId / report URL in Jenkins Pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-pipeline

I have intergrated Sonarqube in Jenkins Pipeline, it working as below define:

```
        stage('static check') {
           steps {
               echo "starting codeAnalyze with SonarQube......"
               //sonar:sonar.QualityGate should pass
               withSonarQubeEnv('sonar') {
                 sh "mvn -f pom.xml clean compile sonar:sonar -U"
               }
               script {
               timeout(10) { 
                   def qg = waitForQualityGate() 
                       if (qg.status != 'OK') {
                         echo "failure: ${qg.status}"
                         
                         # Plan to send notify to Slack, But can NOT to obtain the Sonar report URL or TaskId
                         
                       }
                   }
               }
           }
       }
```

**Plan to send corresponding notify to Slack, But can NOT to obtain the Sonar report URL or TaskId**

And found some guys suggest that use BUILD_LOG_REGEX: `SonarQube result URL: ${BUILD_LOG_REGEX, regex=".*ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse (.*)", showTruncatedLines=false, substText="$1"}`, but this only working in Email Extension Plugin.

Another suggest is compose the report URL by this: `ProjectURL = host + "/dashboard?id=" + ProjectID`, and we not easy to get the ProjectID, since the projectID is compose from Pom.xml as: `groupId:artifactId`.

Maybe there is some easy way to get the Sonar TaskId or Report URL, Especially whether there is the `waitForQualityGate() or other method` will return the Sonar TaskId or Report URL ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see the report by reading the file `./target/sonar/report-task.txt`

Using `def getURL = readProperties file: './target/sonar/report-task.txt'`

and extract by calling something like this `${getURL['dashboardUrl']}` which is will give url of report. also that above file have taskId.

so it should like this

```
def qg = waitForQualityGate() 
 if (qg.status != 'OK') {
 echo "failure: ${qg.status}"
 def getURL = readProperties file: './target/sonar/report-task.txt

 Add your slackmsg here use in that ${getURL['dashboardUrl']}

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

For windows, use

> ./.scannerwork/report-task.txt

Eg

```
 waitForQualityGate abortPipeline: true
 def getURL = readProperties file: './.scannerwork/report-task.txt'
 sonarqubeURL = "${getURL['dashboardUrl']}"
 echo "${sonarqubeURL }"
```